# how can I get b[2] and a[b[2]] * 2 to MIPS

Tags: assembly, mips

I'm studying for an exam but there is a point a didn't understand it

if we have this code :

```
if (B[2] >= 0)

    X = A[B[2]] * 2;
```

how can I get b[2] and a[b[2]] * 2

A and B are an array at this point

Comment: the question was translated from high level to MIPS

Answer (score 2):

1. Arrays are stored in memory, because only memory allows indexing.  The array elements are stored consecutively in memory.
2. That means that the array itself has a memory address (a starting address).  Further that each individual element of the array also has its own unique address.  The address of the the whole array and the address of the first element (e.g. `A[0]`) are the same address — we refer to the whole array by one single address: the address of its least element.  This address is also often called the *base address* of the array.  (In the case of 32-bit machine, an address is just a 32-bit number, which can be held in a single MIPS register.)
3. Modern hardware is byte addressable.  This means that an integer of 4 bytes wide, stored in memory, occupies 4 bytes and also 4 memory addresses.  For example, if A[0] is located starting at 0x1000 then A[1] is starting at 0x1004, 4 bytes further along because A[0] occupies 4 bytes in the range 0x1000-01003.  (We refer to individual elements also using just one address: the lowest address in their range.)
4. The processor can access memory in sizes of 1 byte or, 2 bytes or 4 bytes both/all-4 at once.  You use load instructions to read from memory and store instruction to write to memory — tell the load or store where to read or write and how many bytes (1,2, or 4).  For 2 & 4 byte loads, tell the load instruction the lowest address within the element, and it will fetch consecutive bytes to form a half (2 bytes) or full word (4).  (For loads smaller than 4 bytes you have the option of either sign or zero extending into the 32-bit register.)
5. Each element of a given array has the same type.  The size of the element determines the scale factor.  The scale factor is necessary to convert between an array index and an byte offset for the array.  We write programs using indexes, but since the hardware is byte addressable, the conversion is necessary — except when the element size is 1 byte as with strings, since that is the multiplicative identity — this conversion is done automatically by high level languages, though very visible in assembly.
6. Putting this all together, there is a formula for the address of an element: `baseAddress + index * sizeof(element)`.  The multiplication is due to the scaling necessary, and converts `index` into a byte offset.  The addition then computes the byte address of the `index`th element in the array.

   Given that computed address we can use a load (or store) instruction, which will then finish an indexing operation, e.g. `... = ... C[i] ...;` (or `C[i] = ...;`).
7. If the `index` in question is a constant, like 2, we can perform the multiplication in the above general formula in our heads, e.g. if the element size is 4 byte integer, then 2*4=8, so we know that `A[2]` is located at `A+8`.
8. The MIPS processor offers an addressing mode, called base plus displacement.  The base must be a register holding the address of where to access memory, though the processor will add the small (16-bit) integer constant displacement to the base register's address first, to compute what is called the effective address that is actually used in a memory access.

   If doing `A[i]`, the displacement is not helpful (modulo certain optimization like loop unrolling) so zero (the additive identity) is used for the displacement, but when doing `A[2]`, the displacement can be used to skip the add instruction that would otherwise be part of the formula `baseAddress + index * sizeof(element)`.  (The formula is just as applicable in either case: we could do `A[2]` at multiplying and adding runtime the same way we do `A[i]`, though with the addressing mode, the displacement of the constant `index * sizeof(element)` can be used instead.)

---

To compute `A[B[2]]` we decompose the expression into smaller parts that are individually digestible:

```
temp = B[2];
valueOfInterest = A[temp];
```

Each of these lines should be accessible, given the above.  It is just two array references (one by constant/known index, and one by variable/unknown index).  These are both reads, so there should be one `lw` for each array reference.

If we find an array reference on the right hand side of assignment, `=`, then that requires a store to write memory rather than a load to read memory.

If we have an assignment operator `A[i] += ...;` (or increment/decrement operator: `A[i]++`) that means we have to both load to read memory *and* store to write memory, with both read and write to the same address.

Comment: so if i want to get B[2] first I make lw of 8($b) then another lw for A like lw $B($A) , what about X < X is variable not an array

Comment: That would be nice if MIPS would do it, but it doesn't.  You have to use the formula, of course, here with the pattern for variable index: (1) convert index to byte offset. (2) add byte offset to base array byte address to get byte address for the element at index. (3) dereference that address to access element.